# Animated movie in which people live in a land of branches

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching it on TV, over ten years ago. It was animated, 3D modelled perhaps.

There was a village inside this world of thick wooden branches in every direction. The villagers took it for granted except the protagonists who tried to escape and eventually got out. And I remember in the end it was a huge floating ball of branches.

Comment: Was there no gravity? The scenario looks the same as that described in Larry Niven's *The Integral Trees*.

Comment: @LSerni I think there was. I'm not sure, but I remember the movie was more of a fairy tale, rather than science fiction - if I googled The Integral Trees right.

Comment: Reminds me of Alan Dean Foster's *Midworld*, but that is pretty clearly not a match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might this be ***[Kaena: The Prophecy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0297753/)*** (2003)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaena:_The_Prophecy):

> *Kaena: The Prophecy* (French: Kaena: *La prophétie*) is a 2003 French-Canadian CGI-animated fantasy movie. The United States release of the film is distributed by Destination Films and features the voices of Kirsten Dunst, Richard Harris (in his last role before his death), Anjelica Huston, Keith David and Ciara Janson.

> The film begins with an alien ship crash landing on a desert planet. The alien survivors, known as Vecarians, are quickly killed by the planet's predatory native inhabitants, the Selenites. **The ship's core, Vecanoi, survives, and from it sprouts Axis, a massive tree reaching up into space.**
>
> **600 years later, a race of human-like tree-dwellers have evolved living in the branches of Axis. One of them, a teenager named Kaena (voiced by Kirsten Dunst), is an adventurous daydreamer who longs to explore the world beyond the confines of her village.** Kaena's inquisitiveness is opposed as heresy by the village elder, who commands his people to stay productive and toil for the villager's gods (who are, unbeknownst to them, the Selenites living in the planet below).
>
> Led by prophetic dreams of a world with a blue sun and plentiful water, Kaena eventually defies the elder and climbs to the top of Axis. There, she encounters the ancient alien Opaz (voiced by Richard Harris), the last survivor of the Vecarian race that crash landed on the planet centuries ago. Opaz has used his technology to evolve a race of intelligent worms to serve him and help him escape the planet. Upon learning of Kaena's dreams, Opaz enlists her help in retrieving Vecanoi, which contains the collective memory of his people.
>
> However, Vecanoi rests at the base of Axis, where the Selenites dwell. The Queen of the Selenites (voiced by Anjelica Huston) blames Vecanoi for the destruction of their planet, and has spent most of her life (and sacrificed the future of her people) attempting to destroy it.